# GROUP BY each 6 months in one record

Tags: mysql, group-by, intervals

I am having trouble retrieving certain data from a db through a SELECT query as such:

```
SELECT table.something
FROM table
WHERE table.date BETWEEN 'from' AND 'to'
GROUP BY (each 6 months between the from and to date).
```

Any idea how this can be done without having to recur to a view and an external grouping through code.

Comment: What do you mean with "*each 6 months between the from and to date*"? Show us some example of desired output.. I mean: if startdate is may 15, six months mean up to november 15? Or from may to november? What?

Comment: 6 moths date is fixed. like Jan-Jun and jul-Dec ? or is it variable ?

Comment: I mean that for example, considering that the from date is 2010-1-1 and that the to date is 2012-1-1, the result is to be grouped in such way:

Comment: 2010-1-1 -> 2010-7-1    100 something

Comment: @Bdd: if startdate is May 14?

Comment: 2010-7-1 -> 2011-1-1 120 something

Comment: 2011-1-1 -> 2012-7-1 110 something

Comment: @Bdd: no, I don't get your point. You're not answering my question and your examples are useless, because could be a particular case.

Comment: @Bdd - I agree with Marco, it doesn't clear up anything. You should **edit** your question and add some inputs and **matching expected** outputs.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this will work:

```
SELECT 
    table.something, 
    CEIL(MONTH(date)/6) as monthVALUE 
FROM 
    table 
WHERE 
    table.date BETWEEN 'from' AND 'to' 
GROUP BY 
    monthVALUE
```

Comment: To account for the range being in different years, perhaps do something like `(CEIL(MONTH(date)/6) + YEAR(date)) as monthVALUE` or `CONCAT(CEIL(MONTH(date)/6), '_', YEAR(date)) as monthVALUE`.

Comment: This returned me 2 rows in an interval of two years whereas it should be grouped in 4 rows

Comment: Yes,, some modification is needed in this result,, iam looking into it

Comment: You have to account for the year the date is in. `CEIL(MONTH(date)/6)` will return either 1 or 2 depending on which half of 12 the month is in (Jan-Jun=`1`, Jul-Dec=`2`). So say there are 4 rows with dates in two different years each in different halves of the years, the `CEIL()` will return a result set like `(1,1,2,2)`, so the numbers are grouped into `(1,2)`. But if you concatenate the year onto it, it would look something like `(1_2011, 2_2011, 1_2012, 2_2012)`, so you get four distinct year-halves. See my comment above for proposed implementations.

Comment: Thats right, but in that case, if the start date is 2010-09-13 to 2012-09-13 I get:

Comment: count  date  download_date
295658  2_2010  2010-09-13 00:04:24
337694  1_2011  2011-01-01 00:00:05
466236  2_2011  2011-07-01 00:10:57
293365  1_2012  2012-01-01 00:00:11

Comment: So between the first and second record there is only 4 months interval and not 6

Comment: Try it with `CEIL(DATEDIFF(date, 'from') / 182.6211) as monthVALUE`

Comment: Nop man, the first result is of a day and the rest are of 6 months intervals without the last 2

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by that, but I just realized if the from date and date are less than a day apart, it will create a separate interval for that day. Here is the fix for that: `IF(CEIL(DATEDIFF(date, 'from') / 182.6211) = 0, 1, CEIL(DATEDIFF(date, 'from') / 182.6211)) AS monthVALUE`

Comment: One last question man, what is the purpose of the 182.6211 num

Comment: Actually there's one more slight hiccup with the fact that if your date range contains one or more leapyears (with extra day Feb. 29) and your date range is exactly 1 year: let's say from `2010-09-13` to `2012-09-13`... rows with dates exactly on `2012-09-13` will be grouped into its own interval... unless you want that to happen...?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of worrying about on a single query create a temporary table insert record with the start date and end date and your some other column. and use the select query for each record to get the results and store it in the temporary table and select the temporary table.

Comment: why negative? using temporary tables it can be done. The anwsers like 'some thing like' are not the answers. Negative should be marked only when if the answer is wrong.